# collective noun: "couple" subject verb agreement

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, collective-nouns

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

> how long the couple remain faithful is something questionable.
>
> how long the couple remains faithful is something questionable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Couple" is a collective noun and can be treated as either singular or plural. So that means both of your examples are correct. Here's another example from Cambridge Dictionaries Online:

> An elderly *couple live (US lives)* next door.

The parenthetical supplement "US lives" implies that the singular agreement is more common in the US than in the UK.